# Generic way to isolate faulty component (app / router) on non-working UPnP port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, upnp

I have had trouble finding a guide for how to isolate problems with UPnP port-forwarding. I currently have access to Ubuntu 17.10 beta2 for troubleshooting.

My problem is that I have a Plex Server on a Raspberry Pi 3 that is telling me that its required port is not open on my router (WRT54GS), hence it's not exposed to the internet. The server is allegedly capable of opening the port itself using Upnp.

What I've done:

- Made sure router has Upnp enabled. Disabled/enabled it many times. Restarted it.
- Checked for firmware updates for the router (none exist).
- Used a Upnp app (for Windows 10) to make sure it can "see" the settings on my router (it can -- at least it listed every port forwarding rule in it).
- Made sure that the app (plex server) reports successful port-forwarding when I do a manual port-forward. It does.
- Googled for various keywords but mostly come up with articles about security implications of Upnp exposed to the internet. Not what I was after. I must not have said the magic word.

Is there a good method for isolating the problem? If I could just determine whether it's my router's firmware or the specific app that is at fault it would be much easier to fix.

Comment: There's no firmware updates **from the manufacturer** for that ancient router for many years now but there are alternative firmwares that enhance the functionality of those devices by leaps and bounds: DD-WRT and OpenWRT and also other lesser known alternatives. Now, UPnP is indeed insecure, practical but insecure. If you can avoid it and define only the port forwarding rules required by the apps/services, all the better.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks. The point is that unless I can say for certain that it's the firmware's fault, I would rather not go through the trouble to flash it and risk bricking it just because of this problem. I am willing to do it as a separate project however. This ancient router did pass ShieldsUP! with flying colors though.